# INNER JOIN multiple columns to same column from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I got `hmmd_prm` table that is:

```
| id |  hmmd_id  |  prm1  |  prm2  |  prm3  |  prm4  |  prm5  |  prm6  |  prm7  |  prm8  |  prm9  |  prm10 |
| 1  |     2     |   1    |   2    |   3    |   1    |   2    |   3    |   1    |   2    |  null  |  null  |
| 2  |     3     |   4    |   3    |   2    |   1    |   4    |   3    |   2    |   1    |   4    |   3    |
```

and `lab_prm` table that is:

```
| prm_id |  prm_adi  |  prm_adgr  |  prm_udgr  |  prm_birim  |  prm_ctrl  |
|   1    |    pH     |
|   2    |    O2     |
|   3    | peroxide  |
|   4    |    hum    |
```

and main_hmmd table that has names and pulls names using hmmd_id

I'm trying to get a result like this:

```
| id |  hmmd_id  |  prm1  |  prm2  |  prm3  |  prm4  |  prm5  |  prm6  |  prm7  |  prm8  |  prm9  |  prm10 |
| 1  |   BUGDAY  |   pH   |   O2   | prxide |   pH   |   O2   | prxide |   pH   |   O2   |  null  |  null  |
```

I am using something like this:

```
SELECT hp.id, mh.hmmd_adi, lp1.prm_adi, lp2.prm_adi, lp3.prm_adi, lp4.prm_adi, lp5.prm_adi, lp6.prm_adi, lp7.prm_adi, lp8.prm_adi, lp9.prm_adi, lp10.prm_adi
FROM std_tbl_hmmd_prm AS hp
INNER JOIN std_tbl_main_hmmd AS mh ON mh.id = hp.hmmd_id
INNER JOIN std_tbl_lab_prm AS lp1 ON hp.prm1 = lp1.prm_id
INNER JOIN std_tbl_lab_prm AS lp2 ON hp.prm2 = lp2.prm_id
INNER JOIN std_tbl_lab_prm AS lp3 ON hp.prm3 = lp3.prm_id
INNER JOIN std_tbl_lab_prm AS lp4 ON hp.prm4 = lp4.prm_id
INNER JOIN std_tbl_lab_prm AS lp5 ON hp.prm5 = lp5.prm_id
INNER JOIN std_tbl_lab_prm AS lp6 ON hp.prm6 = lp6.prm_id
INNER JOIN std_tbl_lab_prm AS lp7 ON hp.prm7 = lp7.prm_id
INNER JOIN std_tbl_lab_prm AS lp8 ON hp.prm8 = lp8.prm_id
INNER JOIN std_tbl_lab_prm AS lp9 ON hp.prm9 = lp9.prm_id
INNER JOIN std_tbl_lab_prm AS lp10 ON hp.prm10 = lp10.prm_id
```

It is working as I wanted but I am pretty sure there is a way better solution to this.

**How can I make this simplier?**

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**
What I am trying to achieve is, in the hmmd_prm table I have some materials as `hmmd_id` and user will apply some parameters to those parameters. I made 10 columns for parameters so user can assign max 10 parameters but might also assign 1 or 2 and rest null.

This might not be the best solution to this, since this is my first time doing something like this but I simply didn't want the result showing as multiple entries of same material with different parameters in each row like below.

```
| id |  hmmd_id  |  prms  |
| 1  |     2     |   1    |
| 2  |     2     |   2    |
| 3  |     2     |   3    |
| 4  |     2     |   1    |
| 5  |     2     |   2    |
| 6  |     2     |   3    |
| 7  |     2     |   1    |
```

Comment: I think you want left joins there  -- as written that query would not give those results (besides not having all the data in the examples.)

Comment: You are right! I think I missed while overthinking a better solution to this mess

Comment: I don't think it is a mess -- having left joins in a situation like this is acceptable in a relational data model and performs well if your DB is configured correctly.  I personally always do it that way and don't do the pivot which always seems to perform worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL and Relational Databases are opposite sides of the same coin, they both have normalised data structures baked in to their design.

This is just one sign that the structure your dealing with is not a good fit for SQL and so not a good fit for Relational Databases.  *(A code smell.)*

As such, *some* repetition can be removed by normalising the structure on the fly, and then de-normalising again if you ***must***.

```
SELECT
  hp.id,
  mh.hmmd_adi,
  MAX(CASE WHEN pivot_prm.col_id =  1 THEN lp.prm_adi END)   AS prm1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN pivot_prm.col_id =  2 THEN lp.prm_adi END)   AS prm2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN pivot_prm.col_id =  3 THEN lp.prm_adi END)   AS prm3,
  MAX(CASE WHEN pivot_prm.col_id =  4 THEN lp.prm_adi END)   AS prm4,
  MAX(CASE WHEN pivot_prm.col_id =  5 THEN lp.prm_adi END)   AS prm5,
  MAX(CASE WHEN pivot_prm.col_id =  6 THEN lp.prm_adi END)   AS prm6,
  MAX(CASE WHEN pivot_prm.col_id =  7 THEN lp.prm_adi END)   AS prm7,
  MAX(CASE WHEN pivot_prm.col_id =  8 THEN lp.prm_adi END)   AS prm8,
  MAX(CASE WHEN pivot_prm.col_id =  9 THEN lp.prm_adi END)   AS prm9,
  MAX(CASE WHEN pivot_prm.col_id = 10 THEN lp.prm_adi END)   AS prm10
FROM
  std_tbl_hmmd_prm   AS hp
INNER JOIN
  std_tbl_main_hmmd  AS mh
    ON mh.id = hp.hmmd_id
CROSS APPLY
(
  VALUES
    ( 1, hp.prm1 ),
    ( 2, hp.prm2 ),
    ( 3, hp.prm3 ),
    ( 4, hp.prm4 ),
    ( 5, hp.prm5 ),
    ( 6, hp.prm6 ),
    ( 7, hp.prm7 ),
    ( 8, hp.prm8 ),
    ( 9, hp.prm9 ),
    (10, hp.prm10)
)
  AS pivot_prm(col_id, prm_id)
INNER JOIN
  std_tbl_lab_prm   AS lp
    ON pivot_prm.prm_id = lp.prm_id
GROUP BY
  hp.id,
  mh.hmmd_adi
```

Personally I'd advise ***not*** doing the `GROUP BY` and `MAX(CASE)` to de-normalise the results, and instead just use...

```
SELECT
  hp.id,
  mh.hmmd_adi,
  pivot_prm.col_id,
  lp.prm_adi
FROM
  std_tbl_hmmd_prm   AS hp
INNER JOIN
  std_tbl_main_hmmd  AS mh
    ON mh.id = hp.hmmd_id
CROSS APPLY
(
  VALUES
    ( 1, hp.prm1 ),
    ( 2, hp.prm2 ),
    ( 3, hp.prm3 ),
    ( 4, hp.prm4 ),
    ( 5, hp.prm5 ),
    ( 6, hp.prm6 ),
    ( 7, hp.prm7 ),
    ( 8, hp.prm8 ),
    ( 9, hp.prm9 ),
    (10, hp.prm10)
)
  AS pivot_prm(col_id, prm_id)
INNER JOIN
  std_tbl_lab_prm   AS lp
    ON pivot_prm.prm_id = lp.prm_id
```

This will make many subsequent queries much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You could normalize hmmd_prm so it becomes an intersecting table (many to many). You haven't given enough information about the data to know if this would work. You may also need a position column with values 1 to 10 if the prm1, prm2, etc has any significance.

```
| Id | hmmd_id | prm_id | prm_position |
| 1  | 2       | 1      | 1            |
| 1  | 2       | 1      | 2            |
| 1  | 2       | 1      | 3            |
| 1  | 2       | 1      | 4            |
```

etc.

You could then create a unique constraint across hmmd_id, prm_id and prm_position to ensure integrity.

Comment: This strikes me more as a comment than an answer.

Comment: That's the problem when answering from a phone... it's pretty difficult to create a good example.

Comment: Yeah, I normally answer from a phone too.  It's...laborious

Comment: @Andrew -- so you admit to phoning in this answer?  Good call.

Comment: I'm actually not sure about the structure I'm using is good for this since I've never done something like this before. I updated the question about what I'm trying to achieve. For the sake of the "question answered" I will select @MatBailie 's answer since it was an answer to actual question "How I can make this simplier?"
I asked this mere question because query felt bad since it was repetetive and I felt doing something wrong. I will however try to find better solution to my situation thanks a lot.